# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation: got this error while uploading image

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, pdf, sdk

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation:
[Body] must be an fopen resource, a GuzzleHttp\Stream\StreamInterface object, or something that can be cast to a string. Found bool(false) in /var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php: 65 Stack trace: #0/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(78): Aws\Api\Validator->validate()#1/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(566): Aws\Middleware: : Aws{
closure
}()#2/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(589): Aws\S3\S3Client: : Aws\S3{
closure
}()#3/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(523): Aws\S3\S3Client: : Aws\S3{
closure
}()#4/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/S3Client.php(542): Aws\S3\S3Client: : Aws\S3{
closure
}()#5/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(54): Aws\S3\S3Client: : Aws\S3{
closure
}()#6/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php in**/var/www/html/config/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php** on line **65**
   this is my actual error which i face while uploading pdf or image.

- I tired Permission to the relatable folders.
- Increase Size of Upload_max_size and Post_max_size in php.ini

Want proper guidance/solution of the error why this happens only while uploading in live web, in my local setup it is running smoothly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: $mediadocument = $_FILES['mediadocument']['tmp_name']; here it is not storing mediadocument